# How to Implement a Purely Java Object Cache

Tags: java

I'm trying to train a language model using Java. This involves reading a file, extracting word tokens from the file, and getting the frequency of each unique word token in the file.

I have created a Java object to hold each word and its frequency, and then saved the objects with all words and frequencies in an ArrayList. When extracting closely related words (for example the, that, then, ten, etc), I want to get the word with the hiest frequency first.

I have so far achieved the above functionality, however, each query takes my PC about 25 minutes to execute because it has to, for every query, read the text file, calculate the word frequencies, save these in an ArrayList, and then search through the array for the required word. I believe that caching the ArrayList with words and corresponding frequencies would greatly reduce the time it takes my programme to run.

However, I want to implement my own purely Java object cache. I have googled this but most caching solutions reference third-party implementations, which I would very much like to avoid.

Can anyone help me with details and/or tutorials and sample code on how to create a purely Java object cache?
Any other proposed solutions to my problem are very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: what if you use a Map instead? Then your search would be way faster

Comment: If your Googling finds you third-party implementations, why not peruse through those for sample code?

Comment: How many files are you parsing through? 25 minutes my god.

Comment: Also take a look on this http://acs.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/ you may find it somewhat useful

Comment: How many words does each file (generally) contain and how many unique words are there?  I don't understand what you mean by _"each query"_.  Want constitutes a "query".  Why are you parsing the files every time?  Why not parse them once, do the analysis, and then save the results of the analysis in a different file.  I would think the analysis takes a lot of time but it sounds like something that can be done once (i.e. statically).

Comment: p.s. You might also look into using a database to store the results of the analysis.  If the number of words is large enough to where it's unlikely you can fit the entire results in main memory, then this is exactly what DBs are good at (they will do all sorts of caching).

Comment: The extracted unique words are so far 20,000. By query, I mean search for closely related words. These queries vary because I want to give the users the option to choose which word they would like to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic approach should be along these lines:

```
Map<String,Integer> freqs = new HashMap<String,Integer>();


String[] words = inputString.split(" ");
for (String word: words) {
   Integer count =  freqs.get(word);
   if (count == null) {
      freqs.put(1);
   }
   else {
     freqs.put(word,count + 1);
   }
}
```

Otherwise I would definitely look into 3rd party libraries. Esp. if your are working with large sets.

Comment: of course this is just to point out a basic approach. For example, to simplify things I assume you read the whole thing into a string, but for a large file it is of course better to implement a loop that reads the file in chunks (e.g. lines)

Comment: Thanks; your suggestion was a great help. The execution speed has greatly improved, though I'm now dealing with some unexpected results. Nothing I can't fix though... Thanks again!